# Possible typo in the proof of a proposition?

Tags: probability

My books states the following proposition: Suppose $( A_{\alpha} )_{\alpha \in \Gamma} $ is a collection of pairwise disjoint events and $P$ a probability such that $P(A_{\alpha}) > 0 $ for all $\alpha \in \Gamma $. Then $\Gamma$ must be countable.

### Pf:

Consider the collection $\mathscr{A}_n = \{ A_{\alpha} : P(A_{\alpha}) > \frac{1}{n} \}$ for each $n > 0$. We claim this collection is finite, otherwise we can pick an infinite collection $\{ A_{\alpha_k} \}_{k \geq 1 } $ which is disjoint. Observe we would have that $P( \bigcup_{k \geq 1} A_{\alpha_k} ) = \sum_{k \geq 1} P(A_{\alpha_k} ) = \infty $ which is a contradiction.

#### Now, this is the part of the proof which doesn't make sense to me at all:

Therefore, $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} \mathscr{A}_n = \{ A_{\alpha} : \alpha \in \Gamma \} $ and so $\{ A_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in \Gamma} $ must be countable. QED

Can someone explain to me why this is true or perhaps it is a typo? thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The statements seem fine. The proof could use a few more sentences though. In particular, that for any $x>0$ there exists $n$ such that $x > 1/n$. Then $\mathscr A_n$ is each finite and each $A_\alpha$ is in it for some $n$ and there are only countably many $n$s.

Comment: I don't understand why the last line implies that $\Gamma$ is countable.

Comment: $\{ A_{\alpha} : \alpha \in \Gamma \}$ is shown to be a countable union of finite sets which implies it's countable. and $\Gamma$ is exactly as big as $\{ A_{\alpha} : \alpha \in \Gamma \}$.

Comment: Isnt $\bigcup_{n \geq 1 } \mathscr{A}_n = \{ A_{\alpha} : P(A_{\alpha} ) > 0 \} $ ?

Comment: ^ Yes, and $\{ A_{\alpha} : P(A_{\alpha} ) > 0 \}$ is the same as $\{ A_{\alpha} : \alpha \in \Gamma \}$.

Comment: I don't see why they are the same :S

Comment: @grand_chat can you explain why they are the same? I still cannot understand :(

Comment: To see that $\{ A_{\alpha} : P(A_{\alpha} ) > 0 \}=\{ A_{\alpha} : \alpha \in \Gamma \}$, notice that LHS $\subset$ RHS (obvious because LHS is a collection  of  $A_\alpha$'s) and that RHS $\subset$ LHS (true because by assumption $P(A_\alpha)>0$ for every $\alpha$).