# Showing a distribution can have at most countable jump discontinuities

Tags: probability

Let $P$ be a probability and $F(x)$ a distribution. Show that in general $F$ can have an infinite number of jump discontinuities, but there can be at most countably many:

#### Attempt:

We know $F(x) = P( ( - \infty ,x] ) $. and so $P( \{ x \} ) = F(x) - \lim_{t \to x^-} F(t) $ (IS this correct formula ? ). Assuming this, We know $F$ is not continuoust at $x$ (arbitrary) iff $P( \{ x \} ) > 0 $. We know the events $\{ x \} $ are pairwise disjoint and so the collection $ \{ x : \{ x \} \} $ is countable by previous exercise. But, this collection is the number of discontinuities of $F$.

Is this a correct proof? thanks

Comment: What was the "previous exercise" used at the end of the argument?

Comment: This one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199265/possible-typo-in-the-proof-of-a-proposition

Comment: easy: Given the linked result, what you have above is a correct argument, in my opinion. Note you are correct about the definition of $P(\{x\})$ you use, and as a distribution is always right-continuous your statement characterizing the $x$ at which $F$ is discontinuous is right also.

Comment: Possibly-useful things to ponder: If F is a pure jump function, then the sum of the jumps (all positive, of course) must equal 1. If there is a countable infinity of jumps, then that sum must be a convergent infinite series. If F increases in some places without jumping, then the sum of the jumps can be less than 1. But F can have a very strange appearance: let $r_1, r_2, \dots$ be a list of the countably many rationals, and then put jump $(1/2)^i$ at the $i$th rational. So limits may not be obvious.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo With a jump at each rational, can one get $F(x)$ to be continuous from the right at each $x$ (as required in a distribution)? Maybe so, I don't know...